# How do you set the cache prefix per cache driver in Laravel

Tags: laravel, caching

I maintain a microservice architecture where some of the contained services are required to read from more than one cache service.

The cache prefix across these different cache services is different and as such, I need to set a different cache prefix for each cache service in my Laravel project otherwise Laravel uses a global prefix defined in the cache.php config file.

Here you can see the global Cache Prefix setting:[image]

How do I set this per driver? ie: Redis, DynamoDB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After my own trial and error, I have found that you simply add a 'prefix' key to the driver in the cache.php file as such:
[image]

I could not find this instruction in Laravel's documentation.